# Using Skrollr.js to achieve horizontal effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, skrollr

I am hoping to build a horizontally scrolling website, from my research so far Skrollr.js seems like a good tool however I have ran into some issues.
I am creating multiple scenes that are contained in divs of 2048x768 with a windowsize of 1024x768 and I have also read that Skrollr uses vertical scrolling to achieve the illusion of horizontal scrolling. So I have laid my html out as follows:

```
page content (1024x3072)

-- slides container (1024x3072)

--- slides (1024x768)
----first horizontal content (2048x768) ----second horizontal content (1024x768)
```

I am animating the slides container with the transform property along the horizontal axis like such:

```
<div id="slides"
data-0="transform: translate (-0px,0)"
data-1024="transform: translate (-1024px, 0)"
data-2048="transform: translate (-2048px,0)"
data-3072="transform: translate (-3072px, 0)" >
```

But absolutely nothing happens. Have I followed the right logic here? I adapted it from this tutorial:
https://ihatetomatoes.net/create-scrolling-slideshow-using-skrollr/
Is it possible to achieve what I need with Skrollr or would it be better to try another plugin? I am thinking of trying jInvertScroll.js, but I feel Skrollr has much better functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I made this on [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zb58Lwbm/) hope it helps

```
    <div class = "slide1 s" data-0="left:0px;" data-1000="left:-500px"></div>

<div class = "slide2 s" data-0="left:500px;"data-1000="left:0px"data-2000="left:-500px"></div>

<div class = "slide3 s" data-0="left:1000px;"data-1000="left:500px"data-2000="left:0px"></div>



    .s{
    position:fixed;
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
}
.slide1{
    background:#f1f1f1;
}
.slide2{
    background:#e1e1e1;
}
.slide3{
    background:#262626;
}
```